# Image not appearing in Android Phone gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, android-camera2, android-gallery

I am trying to save a picture taken from the camera and making it appear in the device's gallery.

It's working well for Android Q, but for P the images are not showing up.

I tried to follow the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) as closely as I could

Manifest has:

> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

I'm not getting any crashes or catches, I just don't know why it is not showing up in the gallery, can anyone please point me in the right direction to fix this? Much appreciated.

This method is called from the onActivityResult() when taking a picture from the camera.

```
    private fun saveImageFromCamera(
        activity: Activity,
        imageView: ImageButton,
        photoFile2: File?,
        uriPath: (String?) -> Unit
    ) {
        try {
            // If on Android 10+ save to Pictures folder and private folder
            val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile2)
            val bitmap = getBitmap(activity, savedUri)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    try {
                        saveImage(activity, savedUri, photoFile2!!.name)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    try {
                        if (PermissionsHelper.checkExternalStorageAccess(activity)) {
                            val newFile = createImageFile(activity)
                            addBitmapToFile(newFile, bitmap)
                            galleryAddPic(activity)
                         }

                       } catch (e: IOException) {
                           e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
            imageView.load(savedUri)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Function that writes a bitmap into destination file

```
   fun addBitmapToFile(destinationFile: File, bitmap: Bitmap) {
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos)
        val bitmapData = bos.toByteArray()
        //write the bytes in file
        val fos = FileOutputStream(destinationFile)
        fos.write(bitmapData)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
    }
```

Creating a file to store the image in, using getExternalFilesDir.

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createImageFile(activity: Activity): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME, Locale.US).format(Date())
        val storageDir: File = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply { currentPhotoPath = absolutePath }
    }
```

I do get an error when creating a file at this line:

```
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply { currentPhotoPath = absolutePath }
```

> 2020-07-23 12:01:40.906 14705-14705/app.app W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Not a directory 2020-07-23
> 12:01:40.906 14705-14705/app.app W/System.err:     at
> java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
> 2020-07-23 12:01:40.906 14705-14705/app.app W/System.err:
> at
> java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
> 2020-07-23 12:01:40.906 14705-14705/app.app W/System.err:
> at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948) 2020-07-23 12:01:40.906
> 14705-14705/app.app W/System.err:     at
> java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1862) 2020-07-23 12:01:40.906
> 14705-14705/app.app W/System.err:     at
> app.app.helpers.CameraAndGalleryHelper$Companion.createImageFile(CameraAndGalleryHelper.kt:338)

Getting the bitmap from a Uri, I am able to populate an ImageView from this bitmap, so I know that's not the issue.

```
    fun getBitmap(context: Context, imageUri: Uri): Bitmap? {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(
                ImageDecoder.createSource(
                    context.contentResolver, imageUri
                )
            )
        } else {
            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)?.use { inputStream ->
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the scanner so that the image shows up in the gallery

```
   private fun galleryAddPic(activity: Activity) {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).also { mediaScanIntent ->
            val f = File(currentPhotoPath)
            mediaScanIntent.data = Uri.fromFile(f)
            activity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
        }
    }
```

When using the code above, I can take pictures on devices Android 8 and up without any problems.

But when using a Samsung S6 on Android 7, the images do not show up in the device's gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" for AndroidManifest.xml
How about trying to describe? However, this option will also be removed in the next android12.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my lack of details. I have updated my question.
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" won't work as I am having issues in Android 7